# Not sure why my flexbox item contents are not positioned in the center

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've spent hours reviewing flexbox tutorials on youtube and I cannot figure out why I'm not able to center my flexbox item contents.

I have managed to center the images horizontally by using `text-align: center;` in my flex container.

However this do not affect the list AND it has not centered it vertically, other people seem to use `justify-contents` or `align-items` but it's not really working out for me.

Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/dL72j5gx/1/

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}

.flex-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid red;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu {
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid green;
  align-self: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  align-self: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.MenuLogo {
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
}

.ContentArea {
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid purple;
}

.quLogo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.quCharacter {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.myList {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 30%;
}

.list-group {}

.list-group-item {
  outline: 3px solid black;
}

.list-group-item>a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="MenuLogo">
      <img class="quLogo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" alt="LOGO">
      <div class="myList">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="ContentArea">
      <img class="quCharacter" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="CHARACTER">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

***Thanks in advance!***

**EDIT: Here's a quick image to show what im going for.**
[image: homepagelayout]

Comment: Are you trying to center the 2 images or the list? or both?

Comment: @NickB both, everything in both divs centered in the middle

Comment: These: [[flexbox froggy](https://flexboxfroggy.com/), [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)] helped me when I was learning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply **flex** to parent of element and give `flex-direction:column` to **MenuLogo**

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
  }

.flex-container  {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    border: 5px solid red;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu {
    width: 50%;
    border: 3px solid green;
    align-self: center;
    height: 100%;
}


.content {
    width: 50%;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    align-self: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.MenuLogo{
    height: 100%;
    border: 3px solid yellow;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.ContentArea{
    height: 100%;
    border: 3px solid purple;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}

.quLogo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.quCharacter {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}


.myList {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 30%;
}

.list-group{

}

.list-group-item {
    outline: 3px solid black;
}

.list-group-item > a{
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial scale = 1">
   <title>My Webpage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="menu"> 
     <div class="MenuLogo">
         <img class="quLogo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" alt="LOGO">
         <div class="myList">
  <ul class="list-group">
     <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
     <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
     <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
     </div>

  </div>
 </div> 

    <div class="content"> 
     <div class="ContentArea">
        <img class="quCharacter" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="CHARACTER">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this worked and kept the list within the div too. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you use flexbox, you normally need to apply the properties to multiple different "containers." You would need to add the following 3 properties to the direct parent of the elements:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

In this case, add those 3 properties to the `.MenuLogo` class and the `.ContentArea` class.

You can move the table back underneath the image by putting it in a div that is separate from the `div class="MenuLogo"` div. This div is acting as a container for both items right now, and you would want them to be separate elements.

```css
html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0px;
    }

    .flex-container {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      border: 5px solid red;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .menu {
      width: 50%;
      border: 3px solid green;
      align-self: center;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .content {
      width: 50%;
      border: 3px solid blue;
      align-self: center;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .MenuLogo {
      height: 100%;
      border: 3px solid yellow;
      display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }

    .ContentArea {
      height: 100%;
      border: 3px solid purple;
      display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }

    .quLogo {
      width: 300px;
      height: 100px;
    }

    .quCharacter {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
    }

    .myList {
      padding: 10px;
      width: 30%;
    }

    .list-group {
    }

    .list-group-item {
      outline: 3px solid black;
    }

    .list-group-item>a {
      color: black;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <html>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
         <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial scale = 1">
             <title>My Webpage</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
         </head>
         <body>

 <div class="flex-container">
     <div class="menu"> 
         <div class="MenuLogo">
             <img class="quLogo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" alt="LOGO">
             <div class="myList">
         <ul class="list-group">
             <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
             <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
             <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
             <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
             </div>

         </div>
     </div>  

     <div class="content"> 
         <div class="ContentArea">
         <img class="quCharacter" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="CHARACTER">
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 </div>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
         </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! the images are now centered
Ah i see, i put the menu in a seperate div already called .MyList
Does this div need to be put outside .MenuLogo?

Comment: Yes, you would need to put it outside of the .MenuLogo div so they could get separate formatting properties, or else they will essentially be getting the same styling. Hiren provided a great way to do it with your current code, if you set the flex direction of .MenuLogo as column, but this may give you issues if you are adding more content later on and don't want it to go vertically.

Comment: will do thanks for your help

Sadly i dont really understand how to get the menu under the logo, as its not outside the flex box div, so now its underneath the whole menu and logo area. I dont really know how I would get the menu underneath the logo but still be outside the divider